# 8Th Legendre Polynomial of $e$

Tags: numerical-methods

I am working on a school assignment so U understand if you all are reluctant to give exact answers, but U could really use some guidance. I have a few questions, and to keep things organized i will post only one per thread.  This thread is regarding Legendre, here is the exact question as per my assignment:

```
 Legendre Polynomials
i) Find the Legendre polynomial e8(x) of degree 8.
ii) Evaluate e8(x) at x = −1.0, −0.9, −0.8, . . . , +1.0 to isolate each of the eight roots of e8 in an interval of length 0.1.
iii) Apply Newton’s method to approximate the roots r8,1, . . . , r8,8 of e8 to
within 10−50. Display the roots in a table in increasing order.
iv) Approximate the coefficients c8,1, . . . , c8,8 to within 10−50 and display
their values in a table.
```

Im currently at a total loss on this questions. I dont even really know what `e8` reefers too.

I am using MAPLE to write scripts to calculate these values, so i do not need to pen/paper it.

Edit: 
I have parts i, ii, iii done. Im not sure exactly what `iv` is asking me to do.
(can i attach text files on here somehow?)

Comment: I guess my first question is more related to `e`.  Is that just a variable?

Comment: How can that be? I would guess it the $P_n$ from the Wiki page given by Ross.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look up [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)?  Part i is there.  From there ii should not be too hard.  For iii, there is an expression for the derivative-do you understand how to to Newton's method?  I'm not sure what you mean by "r8,1, . . . , r8,8".  You are right that there should be eight real roots.  I also don't understand question iv.  You have the coefficients of the polynomial in i.

Comment: for i then, you are thinking the `e` is just a variable and should be treated as `x` in the wiki example? Yes, i can do Newton's no problem.

Comment: @Special--k: in the question, e8 seems to be the name of the Legendre polynomial.  So, yes this e8(x) seems to be the same as P_8(x).  I'm not sure what to make of the $e$ in the title.